# Join Dataframe by an array column

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have two dataframes with a column `field` array (string). So is it safe to do the following:

```
df1.join(df2, "field");
```

Similarly in a SQL query on a hive table with an array column

Answer (score 1):

Similar query in Hive

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as df1 
  JOIN SELECT * FROM table2 as df2
  ON (df1.field = df2.field)
```

Reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/es/hive/hiveql_joins.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the equality operator is safe and order-sensitive. You can use [query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55606798/1340767) suggested by Pablo to work in SQL.